# If command won't work on simple calculator (python)

Tags: python

my calculator doesn't working and says syntax error in the "If" command

sry if this is very basic it is my first time coding.

```
 #calculator

#number input

num1 = input("first number: ")

num2 = input("second number: ")

#operation select

print("select operation:")
choice = input ("1=add 2=minus")

#if statement

if choice = 1
    print( ,num1, + ,num2, )
    
else
    print( ,num1, - ,num2, )
```

Comment: Two problems: 1) You need to convert `choice` to an integer. 2) Use `==` for comparison, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: `if choice == 1:` is the correct way to write that. `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment

Comment: 3) You forgot the `:` at the end of `if` and `else`.

Comment: You forgot colons `:` after `else` and `if choice = `1. Also, it needs to be `if choice == 1`. There are numerous other errors but I have no time now.

Comment: This is not the correct kind of question and is caused by typos.

Comment: 4) You can't have `,` at the beginning of an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter expects a `:` after an `if` statement.
Also, equality comparison is `==`.

Something like this:

```
if choice == 1:
    print(num1, "+" ,num2)
else:
    print(num1, "-" ,num2)
```